# $on don't catch $broadcast

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a Angular Project and I want create Authentication mechanism so i have the following controller:

```
angular.module('authModule')
.controller('LoginCtrl', function($rootScope, $location, loginRESTService, UserService){
    var login = this;

    function signIn(user) {
        loginRESTService.login(user)
            .then(function(response) {
                console.log(response);
                user.access_token = response.user_id;
                UserService.setCurrentUser(user);
                $rootScope.$broadcast('authorized');
                $location.path("/formList");
            });
    }
})
```

additional I have a main controller with the following methods

```
angular.module('authModule')
.controller('MainCtrl', function ($rootScope, $state, LoginService, UserService) {
    var main = this;

    $rootScope.$on('authorized', function() {
        console.log("ENTRE CON PERMISO");
        main.currentUser = UserService.getCurrentUser();
    });

    $rootScope.$on('unauthorized', function() {
        console.log("ENTRE SIN PERMISO");
        main.currentUser = UserService.setCurrentUser(null);
        $state.go('login');
    });   
})
```

the problem it's that 'authorized' and 'unauthorized' never was invoked and don't have idea why

my app.js file

```
angular
  .module('pysFormWebApp', [
    ...
    'translateModule',
    'formModule',
    'authModule'
  ])
  .config(function ($routeProvider,  $httpProvider) {
    $routeProvider  
      .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
        controller: 'MainCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'main'
      })    
      .when('/login', {
        templateUrl: 'views/auth/login.html',
        controller: 'LoginCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'login'
      }) 
      .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      });
```

my index.html  (only a part because is so long and is the index that generate yo angular)

```
    <div ng-controller="MainCtrl as main" >
        <button ng-if="main.currentUser" class="btn btn-default navbar-btn" ng-click="main.logout()">Logout <strong>{{main.currentUser.name}}</strong> 
        </button>
    </div>
```

Comment: Check that the controller is already initialized when the event is broadcasted. (Just use `console.log`) This is what happened to me a few days ago. :-)

Comment: Where is `LoginCtrl` used/instantiated? I agree with @MartinVseticka; that is the most common cause of these issues.

Comment: thanks in fact it was the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you are not broadcasting the 'unauthorized' event. because of that the `$rootScope.on('unauthorized')` is not working.

Second. Maybe are running the main controller before the login controller, and because of that your controller doesn't catch the event.

let me know if it solves your problem.

Comment: thanks you are right MainCtrl never was invoked, but I dont have idea why not be invoked. so change the method into a service and work :)